# count logged in users in a GWT application

Tags: gwt

What is the best practice to count logged in users or store some information in a gwt application?

Comment: GWT is a pure client side toolkit and your sesions are logged on the server. Not able to comprehend what you are trying to say. Please rephrase the question.

Comment: i actually dont get it what you can not comprehend, i'm working on a gwt system and i need to show the currently logged in users.

Answer (score 1):

You can store something only using server-side code. Try reading: http://code.google.com/intl/ru/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/clientserver.html

There is information exactly about how to use transport layer for communication with server-side.

Than (on server) you can store in db, text files, etc... On your choice...